# Comparing Django object attributes against a list of objects

Tags: python, django

I have a list of `Song` objects released in the past week in `week_songs`. It can have some duplicate songs, but each song has  a `song_id` associated with it.

I'm trying to get a list of unique songs released in the past week.

This is what I'm doing

```
week_song_list = []
for song in week_songs:
    if song.song_id not in week_song_list:
        week_song_list.append(song)
```

But this seems to be adding all the songs even with the same `song_id`. I know this must have a basic solution. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Just as a side note : your test is wrong - you want `if song not in week_songs`. A `song.song_id` will never compare equal with a `song` instance.

Comment: Yeah, I got that. I should have been comparing against a list of song id's and not song objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As someone pointed out (he deleted the answer), I wasn't keeping a record of seen ids.

This is what I was looking for.

```
week_song_list = []
seen_ids = []
for song in week_songs:
    if song.song_id not in seen_ids:
        week_song_list.append(song)
        seen_ids.append(song.song_id)
```